# NSNumber and others not deallocated upon release

Tags: objective-c, clang, automatic-ref-counting, foundation, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to learn more about manual reference counting.
I created a class with an instance variable and its getter/setter that uses a manual release:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject {
    id bar;
}
- (id)bar;
- (void)setBar:(id)value;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (id)bar {
    return bar;
}

- (void)setBar:(NSNumber*)value {
    [bar release];
    bar = value;
}
@end
```

I then use it like this:

```
int main() {

    Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] init];
    NSNumber *n = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 3];

    [f setBar: n];
    [n release];

    NSLog(@"%@\n", [[f bar] description]);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with Address Sanitizer and I'm expecting it to trap, since `[[f bar] description]` should be calling a method on a deallocated object:

```
clang -fno-objc-arc -fsanitize=address -g -framework Foundation main.m
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1
```

But to my surprise it works fine!

```
2018-04-08 18:18:38.470300-0400 a.out[3457:291626] 3
```

I then tried it with `NSDate` instead to see if it made a difference:

```
NSDate *n = [[NSDate alloc] init];

[c setBar: n];
[n release];
```

And it does:

```
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==3379==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fff0b800018 (pc 0x7fff577f3e9d bp 0x7ffee4491670 sp 0x7ffee44915f8 T0)
==3379==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x7fff577f3e9c in objc_msgSend (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x6e9c)
    #1 0x7fff5841b014 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1014)
...
```

I swizzled `NSNumber`'s `dealloc` method, and found that it wasn't being called:

```
@interface Dealloc: NSObject
@end

@implementation Dealloc
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}
@end

...

method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod([Dealloc class], @selector(dealloc)),
                               class_getInstanceMethod([NSNumber class], @selector(dealloc)));

2018-04-08 18:18:38.470300-0400 a.out[3457:291626] 3
```

Compared to `NSDate`:

```
2018-04-08 18:21:03.899490-0400 a.out[3483:293512] dealloc
2018-04-08 18:21:03.900538-0400 a.out[3483:293512] dealloc
2018-04-08 18:21:03.900598-0400 a.out[3483:293512] dealloc
```

So I then tried it with a bunch of other classes:

- `NSString` **doesn't** get deallocated
- `NSMeasurement` **does** get allocated
- `NSArray` **doesn't** get deallocated
- `NSDictionary` **doesn't** get deallocated
- `NSData` **doesn't** get deallocated
- `NSURL` **does** get deallocated

What's going on here? Why is that only some of these get picked up by Address Sanitizer

Update:

As Rob and rmaddy pointed out, with small integer values for `NSNumber` it is stored as a tagged pointer which doesn't actually allocate any extra memory:

```
(lldb) p/t n (__NSCFNumber *) $1 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101000100111 (int)42
```

The last bit is set to 1 indicating it is tagged, and everything bar the first 4 bits is the integer 42.

For a constant string (`__NSCFConstantString`) with `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"blah"]`, it doesn't seem to be a tagged pointer since the last bit isn't set, but it is still a strange address:

```
(lldb) p n
(__NSCFConstantString *) $1 = 0x0000000100002068 @"blah"
(lldb) p/t n
(__NSCFConstantString *) $2 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000010000001101000 @"blah"
```

`NSDate` and `NSMeasurement` all show up within the "normal" address range > 0x600000000000.

An empty `NSArray` has an address within this range but doesn't deallocate, but filling it up with objects does:

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@2, @3, @5, nil]
```

Comment: Try an `NSNumber` with a large arbitrary value like `65465.23424`. Small integers are specially optimized. Same with static `NSString` values.

Comment: @rmaddy `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:65465.23424]` gets deallocated. Are there other special optimisations like some sort of pool for `NSString` and the other collection types?

Comment: Pretty much of any use of `@"..."` is a static string that won't be deallocated. Not sure about the collection types.

Comment: I assume you know that your setter is invalid & you expect it to fail. You cannot assume that Foundation types will receive a `release`. You can only assume that they will be memory managed according as though they did (i.e. they will not leak; but there is never a promise that you will crash). Small integers, empty collections, and static strings, are special cased. On 64-bit platforms, I think almost all integers are tagged pointers. I believe short strings can become tagged pointers, too. There just is no promise that `release` or `dealloc` will actually be called, only that it will "work."

Comment: An introduction to tagged pointers: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html

Comment: @RobNapier Yup it seems like its a tagged pointer!
For `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 42]` I get
`(lldb) p/t n
(__NSCFNumber *) $1 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101000100111 (int)42`
I'll look further into the other types now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn manual retain release, there are two important details:

1. Don't try and use *any* framework classes to do so save for `NSObject`.  Subclass `NSObject` and do your experiments on said subclass.   Framework objects will often have all kinds of odd implementation details that will be.... **surprising**.
2. Don't use `retainCount` or `CFGetRetainCount()`.   The resulting value is meaningless in the real world.  Think of retain counts as deltas;   you cause it to increase and for every increase you must cause it to decrease.

Also, explore the memory pane in the Xcode debugger.